# Find out which device is actively connected to Network (WiFi)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router

I want to write a shell script, that checks wether my SmartPhone is actively connected (logged in) to the local WiFi.

I tried using ping

```
ping 192.168.0.7
```

That works just fine, but as it requires the smartphone to answer, I would expect that this could empty the battery if its done too frequently. So I am looking for a solution that checks the network status without contacting the smartphone itself.

I can detect which devices my router knows using

```
arp -a
```

,but that way I have no information if the known device is currently logged in or not.

(To clearify: I am on a device in the same network)

Comment: Is your phone set statically? Also, what type of phone

Comment: @Tim I gave the phone a static local IP. It is Android Marshmellow. Ping works (even in standby), but I look for a better solution.

Comment: You could use nmap like what is listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733418/how-can-i-write-a-linux-bash-script-that-tells-me-which-computers-are-on-in-my-l)

Comment: isnt nmap just an automated way to ping for devices (having the same disadvantages like mentioned above)?

Comment: Yes but it seems you can automate it with a script

Comment: Query router's sys log, then `awk` and `sed` could be utilized to create a custom log report.  For example: `Tue Sep  5 16:48:50 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2249]: DHCPREQUEST(br-lan) 192.168.2.41 BB:AA:CC:55:66:77`

`Tue Sep  5 16:48:50 2017 daemon.info dnsmasq-dhcp[2249]: DHCPNAK(br-lan) 192.168.200.41 BB:AA:CC:55:66:77 static lease available`